Apple Pay integration using heartland payment system in php website cause error
integrating Apple Pay using heartland payment system but having problem while connecting to server (heartland)...
I am attaching my apple pay integration as well as server file , please someone help me to integrate this or give me the reference of this because in heartland documentation or SDK there is no example of Apple Pay although they told that they support it.
client side integration code
<script>
    function onApplePayButtonClicked() {

        if (!ApplePaySession) {
            return;
        }

        // Define ApplePayPaymentRequest
        const request = {
            "countryCode": "US",
            "currencyCode": "USD",
            "merchantCapabilities": [
                "supports3DS"
            ],
            "supportedNetworks": [
                "visa",
                "masterCard",
                "amex",
                "discover"
            ],
            "total": {
                "label": "Demo (Card is not charged)",
                "type": "final",
                "amount": "10.00"
            }
        };

        // Create ApplePaySession
        const session = new ApplePaySession(3, request);

        session.onvalidatemerchant = async (event) => {
            try {
                console.log('event', event);
                const response = await fetch('/gp_applepay_validate.php', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        validationURL: event.validationURL
                    })
                });
                console.log('response=====', response);
                const data = await response.json();
                console.log('data=====', data);
                if (data.success) {
                    console.log('inside function success');
                    session.completeMerchantValidation(data.merchantSession);
                } else {
                    console.error('Merchant validation failed:', data.errorMessage);
                    session.abort();
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error during merchant validation:', error);
                session.abort();
            }
        };

        session.onpaymentmethodselected = event => {
            // Define ApplePayPaymentMethodUpdate based on the selected payment method.
            // No updates or errors are needed, pass an empty object.
            const update = {};
            session.completePaymentMethodSelection(update);
        };

        session.onshippingmethodselected = event => {
            // Define ApplePayShippingMethodUpdate based on the selected shipping method.
            // No updates or errors are needed, pass an empty object. 
            const update = {};
            session.completeShippingMethodSelection(update);
        };

        session.onshippingcontactselected = event => {
            // Define ApplePayShippingContactUpdate based on the selected shipping contact.
            const update = {};
            session.completeShippingContactSelection(update);
        };

        session.onpaymentauthorized = async (event) => {
            try {
                console.log('event2', event);
                const response = await fetch('/gp_applepay_authnet.php', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        paymentToken: event.payment.token.paymentData
                    })
                });
                const data = await response.json();

                if (data.success) {
                    session.completePayment(ApplePaySession.STATUS_SUCCESS);
                    alert('Payment successful! Transaction ID: ' + data.transactionId);
                } else {
                    session.completePayment(ApplePaySession.STATUS_FAILURE);
                    alert('Payment failed: ' + data.errorMessage);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error during payment authorization:', error);
                session.completePayment(ApplePaySession.STATUS_FAILURE);
                alert('An error occurred during payment. Please try again later.');
            }
        };

        session.oncouponcodechanged = event => {
            // Define ApplePayCouponCodeUpdate
            const newTotal = calculateNewTotal(event.couponCode);
            const newLineItems = calculateNewLineItems(event.couponCode);
            const newShippingMethods = calculateNewShippingMethods(event.couponCode);
            const errors = calculateErrors(event.couponCode);

            session.completeCouponCodeChange({
                newTotal: newTotal,
                newLineItems: newLineItems,
                newShippingMethods: newShippingMethods,
                errors: errors,
            });
        };

        session.oncancel = event => {
            // Payment canceled by WebKit
        };

        session.begin();
    }
</script>

my validateURL file
<?php

include("includes/top.php");
pageSSL("yes");

require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/globalpayments/php-sdk/autoload_standalone.php');

// Handle merchant validation
$validationUrl = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))->validationURL;

// Use the validation URL to request a merchant session from Apple
$merchantSession = fetchMerchantSession($validationURL);

if ($merchantSession['success']) {
    echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'merchantSession' => $merchantSession['merchantSession']]);
  } else {
    echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'errorMessage' => $merchantSession['errorMessage']]);
  }

function fetchMerchantSession($validationURL)
{
    try {
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', $validationURL);
        if ($response->getStatusCode() === 200) {
            $merchantSession = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
            return [
                'success' => true,
                'merchantSession' => [
                    'version' => 3,
                    'merchantIdentifier' => $merchantSession['merchantIdentifier'],
                    'domainName' => $merchantSession['domainName'],
                    'displayName' => $merchantSession['displayName']
                ]
            ];
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Error fetching merchant session: HTTP code ' . $response->getStatusCode());
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return ['success' => false, 'errorMessage' => $e->getMessage()];
    }
}


function fetchAppleMerchantSession($validationURL)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $validationURL,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($httpCode === 200) {
        return json_decode($response, true);
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Error fetching merchant session: HTTP code ' . $httpCode);
    }
}


my token process file i.e
<?php
// Load any necessary dependencies or configuration
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/globalpayments/php-sdk/autoload_standalone.php');

use GlobalPayments\Api\Entities\Enums\PaymentDataSourceType;
use GlobalPayments\Api\ServiceConfigs\Gateways\PorticoConfig;
use GlobalPayments\Api\Entities\Exceptions\ApiException;
use GlobalPayments\Api\Entities\Exceptions\BuilderException;
use GlobalPayments\Api\Entities\Exceptions\ConfigurationException;
use GlobalPayments\Api\Entities\Exceptions\GatewayException;
use GlobalPayments\Api\Entities\Exceptions\UnsupportedTransactionException;
use GlobalPayments\Api\PaymentMethods\CreditCardData;
use GlobalPayments\Api\ServicesContainer;



$paymentToken = $_POST['paymentToken'];

$transactionResult = processPayment($paymentToken);

if ($transactionResult['success']) {
    return json_encode(['success' => true, 'transactionId' => $transactionResult['transactionId']]);
} else {
    return json_encode(['success' => false, 'errorMessage' => $transactionResult['errorMessage']]);
}


function processPayment($paymentToken)
{
    try {
        $config = new PorticoConfig();
        $config->secretApiKey = 'my secret key of heartland account';
        ServicesContainer::configureService($config);

        $card = new CreditCardData();
        $card->token = $paymentToken;
        $card->paymentSource = PaymentDataSourceType::APPLEPAYWEB;

        $response = $card->charge(10.00)
            ->withCurrency('USD')
            ->withAllowDuplicates(true)
            ->execute();

        return ['success' => true, 'transactionId' => $response->transactionId];
    } catch (BuilderException $e) {
        return ['success' => false, 'errorMessage' => 'FailureBuilderException: ' . $e->getMessage()];
    } catch (ConfigurationException $e) {
        return ['success' => false, 'errorMessage' => 'FailureConfigurationException: ' . $e->getMessage()];
    } catch (GatewayException $e) {
        return ['success' => false, 'errorMessage' => 'FailureGatewayException: ' . $e->getMessage()];
    } catch (UnsupportedTransactionException $e) {
        return ['success' => false, 'errorMessage' => 'FailureUnsupportedTransactionException: ' . $e->getMessage() . $e->getCode()];
    } catch (ApiException $e) {
        return ['success' => false, 'errorMessage' => 'FailureApiException: ' . $e->getMessage()];
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return ['success' => false, 'errorMessage' => 'An unknown error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage()];
    }
}


now I am getting the syntax error or something in safari
can someone fix this or give me the example of integration using heartland payment system on php website
I have try heartland documentation but I can't se any implementation of Apple Pay clearly

“now I am getting the syntax error or something in safari” - can you be more specific?

Hi chris, actually this is sample code which i integrate but i want some references so that i can integrate my apple pay also currently my main error is i am not able validate my merchant, i want some references how to validate my merchant
